# Capybara poltergeist WebSocket network error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, phantomjs, capybara, poltergeist

I have just switched to the poltergeist driver after using selenium. However, some of the javascript events aren't being triggered. So I ran the debug option `page.driver.debug` to see the console output and I see a lot of instances of the following error

> WebSocket network error: The issuer certificate of a locally looked up certificate could not be found

I have a feeling this may be blocking JS events from firing after this but have no idea what the cause would be.